# Previous apt-get update & install Docker layer removed during every build

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, dockerfile, apt-get

I have a Dockerfile containing the following:

```
FROM ubuntu:17.10
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
python3-pip \
python3-numpy \
ffmpeg \
python3.6 \
xz-utils
...
```

The layer created at the `RUN` statement is removed every time I run `docker build` and I'm not sure why this is the case. Installing all the dependencies takes a long time, so I'd like for Docker to cache that layer and use it again in the future.

What can I do to get that behaviour?

Thank you.

Comment: Do the contents of the current directory which you're `ADD`ing in also change between builds?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I'd say that this question about a practical error developing a DockerFile is very much [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) since this question covers **1** _software tools commonly used by programmers (ie docker);_ and is **2**_a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development (why else would you need a docker container?)_. It helped me with my problem at least :shrug:.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#build-cache), if one layer's cache is invalidated, subsequent layer will need to be re-built. Hence, it's best practice to have all static steps first in Dockerfile (e.g. in your case, you can move `RUN apt-get ...` command up). Hope it clear

> For the ADD and COPY instructions, the contents of the file(s) in the
>   image are examined and a checksum is calculated for each file. The
>   last-modified and last-accessed times of the file(s) are not
>   considered in these checksums. During the cache lookup, the checksum
>   is compared against the checksum in the existing images. If anything
>   has changed in the file(s), such as the contents and metadata, then
>   the cache is invalidated.
>
> Once the cache is invalidated, all subsequent Dockerfile commands will
>   generate new images and the cache will not be used.